# code not working for mt Task 3 A453 computing, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
import json
sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
splitsentence = sentence.split() 
score = [0]
print(sentence)
for count, i in enumerate(splitsentence): 
    if splitsentence.count(i) < 2:
        score.append(max(score)+1)
    else:
        score.append(splitsentence.index(i) +1)
score.remove(0)
print(splitsentence)
print(score)

numberandwordarrays = [score,splitsentence]


numberandword = open("numberandword.txt" , "w")
json.dump(numberandwordarrays, numberandword)
numberandword.close()
menu = input("Decompress? Y/N: ")
if menu.lower() == "y":
    joinwords = open("numberandword.txt", "r")
    recreate = json.load(joinwords)
    jointwords = recreate[1]
    positions = recreate[0]
    print(" ".join(map(jointwords.__getitem__, map(int, positions))))
else:
    print ("Thanks for using my program, have a good day!")
```

Hi, i am currently doing GCSE computing and this is my code for a453 Task 3. i am trying to split a sentence then save it as well as showing the position of each word. At the end I need an option to reconstruct the sentence from the file. When i run my code everything works fine until i get to the reconstructing part where either it recreates the sentence in a very jumbled order or it displays this syntax error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Computing\a453\Task 3.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(" ".join(map(jointwords.__getitem__, map(int, positions))))
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

does anyone know what ive done wrong and how i can fix it?

Comment: Please paste your code as *text* in your question.

Answer (score 0):

At least on of the indexes extracted from the *positions* list (or iterable) is out of range in the *jointwords* list.

Add a breakpoint on this line and debug.

Comment: thanks for the help but im a beginner in python so i am not too sure how to add breakpoints could you possibly explain how i would add one to my code.